# Singular or plural verb for subjunctive mood

Tags: grammar

1. She requested that he raises his hand.
2. She requested that he raise his hand.

Should I use singular or plural verb for subjunctive mood?

In the example above, which is the correct sentence? Or how should I rewrite the sentence?

Comment: A subjunctive clause uses the plain (infinitive) form of the verb. Your second example is correct, but note that "raise" is neither singular nor plural, but a plain(infinitive) form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sentence 2 is correct. See more examples:

> The family or the legal guardians of a mentally ill person have the right to request that he **leave** the hospital at any time.
>
> An investigating officer took a statement from him on the same day, but ignored Mr. Kooper's request that he **receive** medical treatment.
>
> The Council also extended the Special Representative's mandate by a further three years, with the request that he "**operationalize**" the framework.

Note that we shall use "be" after "that" in this formal construction:

> I request that he **be** removed.
>
> We requested that the next meeting **be** held on a Friday.